# Carriage return replacements to &#13; by nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Carriage returns (used in windows new lines) are replaced to `&#13;` by nokogiri

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<a>ABC</a>\n"
xml.xpath('a').first.content = "testing\r\nnewlines"                      
> "testing\r\nnewlines"
xml.to_s
> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<a>testing&#13;\nnewlines</a>\n"
```

1) Why Nokogiri does that?

2) Is there a way to avoid doing it?

Answer (score 1):

It's because a bug on libxml2 which incorrectly escapes `\r` when shouldn't do as is a valid XML value.

More information here

https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1356

The only solution I can see now is do

```
.gsub("&#13;", "\r")
```

Answer (score 0):

Encoding might be the problem. It is converting \r to its HTML code.

Try setting encoding to one of these formats
doc = Nokogiri.XML('', nil, 'EUC-JP')
doc = Nokogiri.XML('', nil, 'windows-1252')
doc = Nokogiri.XML('', nil, 'ISO-8859-1')

Refer: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html